# C++ ForEach macro to perform variadic operations

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to learn how macros works (using MS Visual Studio) and I don't understand the behavior. I've defined this macro:

```
#define _fe_0(_call, ...)
#define _fe_1(_call, x) _call(x)
#define _fe_2(_call, x, ...) _call(x) _fe_1(_call, __VA_ARGS__)
#define _fe_3(_call, x, ...) _call(x) _fe_2(_call, __VA_ARGS__)
#define _fe_4(_call, x, ...) _call(x) _fe_3(_call, __VA_ARGS__)

#define _GET_NTH_ARG(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, N, ...) N

#define CALL_MACRO_X_FOR_EACH(x, ...) \
    _GET_NTH_ARG("ignored", ##__VA_ARGS__, \
    _fe_4, _fe_3, _fe_2, _fe_1, _fe_0)(x, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Then I defined these actions:

```
#define MY_DECL_1(X) int X;
#define MY_DECL_2(X, Y) X Y;
```

I don't understand why the second operation doesn't work, somebody could help me?

```
CALL_MACRO_X_FOR_EACH(MY_DECL_1, myVar1, myVar2) // OK
CALL_MACRO_X_FOR_EACH(MY_DECL_2, (int, myVar3), ( int, myVar4) ) // ERROR
```

Comment: Could it be that the preprocessor interprets `(int, myVar3)` as 2 arguments, `(int` and `myVar3)`?

Comment: my fault, I've fixed the example

Comment: Macros are really not suitable for this. Regular functions and occasionally templates are much better.

Comment: I know, I just want to understand how to do it